# Como posso criar uma expressão regular que aceite um determinado número no maximo uma vez

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou aprendendo a utilizar Regex e gostaria de saber se tem como eu fazer com que ela aceite no maximo um número 2 em alguma sequencia (podendo conter letras ou numeros)

Ex.:
"sskfdam09471928" 
Aprovado

"asldk02210920139"
Reprovado por repetir duas vezes

Answer (score 9):

Com regex podes fazer isso assim:

```js
const a = 'sskfdam09471928';
const b = 'asldk02210920139';

function validar(str) {
  return !!str.match(/^[^2]*2?[^2]*$/);
}
console.log(validar(a)); // true
console.log(validar(b)); // false
```

A ideia da regex é:

- `^[^2]*` - nenhum `2` no inicio da string, 0 vezes ou mais
- `2` - um `2` no meio da string
- `[^2]*$` nenhum `2` no final da string, 0 vezes ou mais

Maneiras alternativas:

```
function validar(str) {
  return str.indexOf('2') === str.lastIndexOf('2');
}

function validar(str) {
  return str.split('').filter(char => char === '2').length <= 1;
}
```

Comment: Ok, obrigado por ter me ajudado, consegui entender

Comment: Ou algo assim que daria true para os reprovados: https://regex101.com/r/KXNrdM/1

Comment: @bfavaretto e que tal uma resposta? ;) essa solução com `!` fica mais curta que a minha

Comment: @bfavaretto essa regex com casos de `2` espalhados pela string já não dá... só lado a lado

Comment: @Sergio você conhece outras formas de resolver isso? Eu querendo aprender formas diferentes, apesar dessa já ter me ajudado

Comment: @Rodolfo, acho que a minha interpretação foi diferente da do Sergio. Não pode ter sequência de `2`, ou não pode haver mais de um `2`  na string?

Comment: Não poder haver mais de um 2 na string

Comment: Então meu link acima não vale, vale esta resposta. Possivelmente tem outras maneiras com regex. E tem como resolver esse mesmo problema sem regex também. @Rodolfo

Comment: Obrigado, tratarei de buscá-las!

Answer (score 8):

Apenas para dar mais uma alternativa, também da para resolver com uma regex utilizando *positive lookahead*:

```
2(?=.*2)
```

Explicação

```
2   - Procura pelo 2
(?= - Que tenha à frente
.*  - Qualquer coisa
2)  - E outro dois
```

Esta regex indica se o `2` se repete. Se pretende saber se não se repete basta inverter o resultado com um *not* `!`.

Exemplo:

```js
console.log(!/2(?=.*2)/g.test("sskfdam09471928"));
console.log(!/2(?=.*2)/g.test("asldk02210920139"));
```